# How Do I Make Texts in Table have outline on PowerPoint with C#?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

can't make 'text outline' of texts in table cell VISIBLE

```
var sel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
sel.TextRange2.Font.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
sel.TextRange2.Font.Line.Transparency = 1;
```

code above makes texts in shape anti-aliased. the same won't work with texts in cells of table. I've tried below, which only made the texts bold. It seems the Font(actually Font2) object to be read-only, but I can do the same on Powerpoint manually

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var sel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
    try
    {
        var tab = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table;
        int col = sel.ShapeRange.Table.Columns.Count;
        int row = sel.ShapeRange.Table.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= col; j++)
            {
                tab.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                tab.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                tab.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Line.Transparency = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```